# How can I check to see if the parameters in a constructor for an interface and the class is the same?

Tags: java, interface

As mentioned in my title, I want to be able to compare my inputs within the constructor. But I just don't understand it at all, why we have two objects setting the parameters.

Please help TvT

I have an interface called vehicle with the following methods:

```
public String getName();
public int getTopSpeed ();
public int getMaxPassengers ();
```

I have tired:

```
if (v.getMaxParameters <0 || maxParameter <0) 
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
else 
     return maxParameter;
```

but i get nullpointerexception error and yah im probably doing this completely wrong. im so confused....

```
public class Car implements Vehicle {

    String name;
    int speed;
    int maxPassenger;
    double weight;
    public Vehicle v;

    public Car(String name, int speed, int maxPassenger, double weight) {       
        if (v.getName().length() <0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        else 
            this.name = name;

        if (speed < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        else 
            this.speed = speed;

        if (maxPassenger <0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else 
            this.maxPassenger = maxPassenger;

        if (weight<0 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else
            this.weight= weight;
    }
}
```

This is what im trying to test and it should be "failure" as passengers different values.

```
try {  
    Vehicle v = new Car(" ", 280, 5, 2.1);
    Car c = new Car("BMW", 280, 5, 2.1);
    System.out.println(v.getName());
    System.out.println(v.getTopSpeed());
    System.out.println(c.getMaxPassengers());
    System.out.println(c.getWeight());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    System.out.println("failure");
}
```

and this one is failure too as the names are different/ empty

EIDITED

Comment: There is no such thing as 'a constructor for an interface'. `String.length()` cannot be negative. Most of your other tests should be `<= 0`, not `< 0`.

Comment: @Anika In both cases object created is of class `Car`. As noted above, an [Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) cannot be instantiated. Print the value of `v.getName().length()` and you will be able to understand why `< 0` is not working. Again as noted above length cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I am editing the answer after clarification. We can simply override equals or implement Comparator to compare the same. If the instances are of different type doesn't make sense and equals is returning false but if they are of same type we can compare them

```
interface Vehicle
{
    public String getName(); 
    public int getSpeed();
    public int getMaxPassenger();
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v = new Car("abc", 1, 1, 2);
        Car c = new Car("abc", 1, 1, 2);
        if (v.equals(c))
            System.out.print("They are equal");
        else
            System.out.print("They are not equal");
    }

    String name;
    int speed;
    int maxPassenger;
    double water;

    public Car(String name, int speed, int maxPassenger, double water) {       
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        else 
            this.name = name;

        if (speed < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        else 
            this.speed = speed;

        if (maxPassenger <0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else 
            this.maxPassenger = maxPassenger;

        if (water <0 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else
            this.water = water;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getMaxPassenger() {
        return maxPassenger;
    }

    public void setMaxPassenger(int maxPassenger) {
        this.maxPassenger = maxPassenger;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + maxPassenger;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + speed;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(water);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Car other = (Car) obj;
        if (maxPassenger != other.maxPassenger)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (speed != other.speed)
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(water) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.water))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello! thanx for the comment, I have already tried this but this does not help with the test. I get input with `Vehicle v = new Car("  ", 5, 10, 14.15);`
                         `Car c = new Car("Simons", 5, 10, 14.15);` where i should as V name is empty. So i need some way to check V in Car and C's parameter inputs.

Comment: Also if I already have a constructor setting the instance variables, do I still needed a setter?

Comment: Can you please elaborate where are you setting Vehicle in ship?  If you pass it in constructor and set it may be that will serve the purpose. public Ship(Vechicle v, String name ...) if I got it correctly.

Comment: You are inheriting from Vehicle and you have a Vehicle instance variable. The latter one you need to set before using. You can pass in the Constructor or set it through setter.

Comment: sorry i just edited it my original question, its just Vehicle interface and Car class. I think i understand my minstake if I understand correctly both objects v and c are refering to the same constructor? `if (name.trim().length() > 0)
   {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
   }
  else 
  this.name = name;` When I use this for the name valadiation it finally works for my test as I i do catch failure. At the end i suppose my  real question is if these two objects can be compared to each other (vehicle v in car class and car c in car class)

Comment: Yes.  You can use equals or can use comparator for that. Let me post code in another answer.